# Simple Signal Handling in Scrapy/Python giving error

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to catch the `closed` Signal in scrapy the following code.

And this is my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
signal.signal(scrapy.signals.spider_closed,scrapy_clean_up)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

This is the code

```
import scrapy
import signal,os

def scrapy_clean_up():
    print "scrapy has closed!"

signal.signal(scrapy.signals.spider_closed,scrapy_clean_up)
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach to have a Scrapy signal handler is to use the `dispatcher`:

```
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

dispatcher.connect(scrapy_clean_up, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_closed)
```